# Doubt regarding what is $\triangle $ $R(x)(r)?$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm given a linear function $R:X\to Y$ .Then it is given $\triangle R(x)(r)=Rr.$
Can anyone please explain me what does the notation $\triangle $ $R(x)(r)$ means and denotes .. and how is it equal to $Rr$.

Comment: See the answer of Christian Blatter and check the *definition* of $\Delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit or derivative involved here. When $R:\>X\to Y$ is any function
then by definition
$$\Delta R(x,r):=R(x+r)-R(x)\ ;$$
see also the following answer:  [Terminology: Delta vs... absolute?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799444/terminology-delta-vs-absolute/995184#995184)

When $R$ is linear we therefore get
$$\Delta R(x,r):=R(x+r)-R\>x=R\>r\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

**If** $\Delta$ is the differential, then $\Delta R$ is constant: namely, $\Delta R(x)=R$ for all $x$. See [What do we mean by Derivative of linear function is a constant function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005530/what-do-we-mean-by-derivative-of-linear-function-is-a-constant-function/1005544#1005544).

Comment: I know I asked the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005530/what-do-we-mean-by-derivative-of-linear-function-is-a-constant-function/1005544#1005544....why I'm asking this question is because of the following reason :the book I'm using has the proof for derivative of a linear function i.e. $R'(a)=R$ for all $a\in X$ . as follows: if $R:X\to Y$ is a linear function .Then  $\triangle R(x)(r)=Rr.$ and $\|\triangle R(x)(r)-Rr\|=0$ for all $x,r \in X$.This shows that $D~R(x)=R$...

Comment: In Short I mean to say that my proof already uses the fact $\triangle R(x)(r)=Rr.$ in proving that $R'(a)=R$ for all $a \in X$

Comment: @cool, your book *proves* that in fact $R′(a)=R$ for all $a$ when $R$ is linear. $R$ *verifies* the definition of $R'(a)$.

Comment: can't understand what you mean by   "for all $a$ when $R$ is linear."in your previous comment, can you please explain..

Comment: @coool, that in the *proof* (read again http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005530/what-do-we-mean-by-derivative-of-linear-function-is-a-constant-function/1005544#1005544) is *essential* that $R$ be linear.

Comment: moreover does it mean that the proof in my book is not a proof ,it's just the verification that $R$ is that map that satisfies to be the derivative of $R'(a)$ for all $a\in X$

Comment: A verification is a very simple *proof*.

Comment: sorry, but just one last doubt before accepting answer...in this verification how did we pre-define or use the fact  $\triangle R(x)(r)=Rr$ ..from where does it arrive..

Comment: Now I'm in my smartphone. Later, I will edit the answer with more details.

Comment: alright .but please do it as soon as possible for you ..